# Posts that probably need editing

Tags: sql, t-sql, stackexchange

I wrote this [Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/572295/posts-that-probably-need-editing) (reproduced below) some time ago that helped identify posts containing potential spelling/punctuation errors and earned me a Copy Editor badge on Anime.SE.

```
SELECT DISTINCT PostTypes.Name AS [Post Type],
                Posts.Score AS [Post Score],
                Posts.Id AS [Post Link],
                Posts.LastActivityDate AS [Last Activity]
FROM Posts
INNER JOIN PostTypes
ON Posts.PostTypeId = PostTypes.Id
INNER JOIN Users
ON Posts.OwnerUserId = Users.Id
INNER JOIN PostHistory
ON Posts.Id = PostHistory.PostId
WHERE Posts.Score > 0 AND -- Low quality posts are probably not worth salvaging
      Posts.ClosedDate IS NULL AND
      Users.Reputation < 4000 AND -- Posts by trusted users are exempt from editing (that is the theory anyway)
      (
          (
              Posts.PostTypeId IN (1, 3) AND
              Posts.Id <> ALL (
                  SELECT DISTINCT PostId
                  FROM PostHistory
                  WHERE PostId = PostHistory.PostId AND
                        PostHistoryTypeId IN (14, 15)
                  GROUP BY PostId
                  HAVING COUNT(PostHistoryTypeId) % 2 = 1
              )
          ) OR -- Locked posts can't be edited
          (
              Posts.PostTypeId IN (2, 3) AND
              Posts.ParentId <> ALL (
                  SELECT DISTINCT PostId
                  FROM PostHistory
                  WHERE PostId = Posts.ParentId AND
                        PostHistoryTypeId IN (14, 15)
                  GROUP BY PostId
                  HAVING COUNT(PostHistoryTypeId) % 2 = 1
              )
          ) OR
          Posts.PostTypeId IN (4, 5)
      ) AND
      (
          (
              Posts.Title NOT LIKE '%?' AND
              (
                  LOWER(Posts.Title) LIKE 'is %' OR
                  LOWER(Posts.Title) LIKE 'are %' OR
                  LOWER(Posts.Title) LIKE 'do[en ]%' OR
                  LOWER(Posts.Title) LIKE '%wh[aeoy]%' OR
                  LOWER(Posts.Title) LIKE '%how%'
              )
          ) OR
          (
              Posts.Title LIKE '[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]%' OR
              Posts.Title LIKE '%[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]([ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrtuvwxyz]%' OR
              Posts.Title LIKE '%[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrtuvwxyz])[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]%' OR
              Posts.Title LIKE '%[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz],[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]%' OR
              Posts.Title LIKE '% i[ '']%'
          ) OR
          (
              Posts.Body LIKE '[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]%' OR
              Posts.Body LIKE '%[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]([ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrtuvwxyz]%' OR
              Posts.Body LIKE '%[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrtuvwxyz])[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]%' OR
              Posts.Body LIKE '%[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz],[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]%' OR
              Posts.Body LIKE '% i[ '']%'
          )
      )
ORDER BY Posts.LastActivityDate DESC
```

Is there any way to speed this up and, more importantly, simplify the query expression? Especially the part where I list the letters of the alphabet in both upper and lower cases, because I think in SQL, `[A-Za-z]` doesn't give what I want.

Comment: Does stackexchange's query runner accept `ILIKE` (case-insensitive LIKE?). That's the only thing I can think of. Since you're doing some `LIKE`s without a % at the end (it's at the beginning for example), the query runner can't use text indexes to speed up the query. Maybe do a subquery using just `LIKE 'something%'` and then query the result? I'm guessing the query runner doesn't have `EXPLAIN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Formatting

I really like my SQL queries to be formatted a certain way. For example, if I'm retrieving multiple columns I typically do something like

```
SELECT
    col1
    ,col2
    ,col3
    ,col4
FROM mytable
```

I thought it was **super** ugly at first, but having each on its own line is nice for readability (I don't like having them on the same line as the `SELECT` either, same reason). Putting the comma at the front of the line seems kinda weird, but I do like that I don't have to try and remember to add commas at the EOL if I grab more columns, which is an error I used to run into all of the time.

I like to format my `JOIN`s a certain way as well, for example

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 AS Alias1
     JOIN Table2 AS Alias2
         ON Alias1.Column1 = Alias2.Column3
```

I find that this makes it much easier to visually separate each table, or CTE, or sub-query, that is being joined. I also find that it makes the conditions by which they're joined much easier to distinguish as well.

Lastly, I find that when combining multiple conditions it is a lot nicer to have the boolean logic (`AND`/`OR`) to be at the beginning of the line; then I just look at a single column to see how that row is combined with everything else.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE (COND1
       AND COND2
       AND COND3)
      OR COND4;
```

---

#### Use constants

Right now you have a bunch of magic numbers all over the place, e.g.

```
Posts.Score > 0
Users.Reputation < 4000
Posts.PostTypeId IN (1, 3) AND
PostHistoryTypeId IN (14, 15)
```

I personally really like to have constants for values where it makes sense. In this case, I'd probably rewrite those lines to look like this

```
DECLARE @MinPostScore int = 0
DECLARE @MaxReputation int = 4000
DECLARE @PostTypes TABLE (Value int)
INSERT INTO @PostTypes VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO @PostTypes VALUES (3)
DECLARE @PostHistoryTypes TABLE (Value int)
INSERT INTO @PostHistoryTypes VALUES (14)
INSERT INTO @PostHistoryTypes VALUES (15)

...

Posts.Score > @MinPostScore
Users.Reputation < @MaxReputation
Posts.PostTypeId IN (SELECT Value FROM @PostTypes) AND
PostHistoryTypeId IN (SELECT Value FROM @PostHistoryTypes)
```

You may also find it helpful to declare values used repeatedly (i.e. `'[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]'`) as variables and insert/concat as needed.

---

#### Comments per clause in `WHERE`

A number of these clauses don't make a lot of sense to a lay reader (mostly because I don't know much about SEDE) - variables instead of magic numbers would help, but maybe a comment describing the query (or replacing it with a function, if performance/SEDE allows it) would help.

---

#### Character classes

According to [msdn](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql) you can use character ranges with `LIKE`. This would make the last few lines look like this:

```
Posts.Title LIKE '[a-z]%' OR
Posts.Title LIKE '%[A-Za-z]([A-Za-z]%' OR
Posts.Title LIKE '%[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z]%' OR
Posts.Title LIKE '%[A-Za-z],[A-Za-z]%' OR
Posts.Title LIKE '% i[ '']%'
```

You can then simplify this even more, like so

```
Posts.Title LIKE '[a-z]%' OR
Posts.Title LIKE '%[A-Za-z][(),][A-Za-z]%' OR
Posts.Title LIKE '% i[ '']%'
```

Unfortunately the columns you're comparing use case-sensitive collation (played around using [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/view-collation-information) to figure that out) so you can't just leave out one version. SEDE is run on T-SQL, so it won't support the `iLIKE` operator either.

---

#### Short circuiting

Unfortunately, [short circuiting isn't guaranteed](http://rusanu.com/2009/09/13/on-sql-server-boolean-operator-short-circuit/) in T SQL, so we can't guarantee any optimizations here, however if you carefully examine your conditions you might find ways where you can take advantage of short-circuiting if it were to occur. For example, you might choose to place the "most likely" case first, or use [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to switch up the order such that each case is mutually exclusive. YMMV.

Comment: So I checked with the last command in the msdn link you provided, the Title column has `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` as its collation. I ran your code rewritten using character classes, but it just returns all question titles, unless I add `COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN` after each LIKE clause. Is there a way to specify the collation just once?

Comment: @Gao not to my knowledge, no.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the query (link in the question) to address most of the points you've raised, and it really looks much nicer now. SEDE reports that the query completed in 355 ms for Anime.SE, 2725 ms for Workplace.SE, but failed to run for CodeReview.SE. I guess it's just not suited to be run on this site where posts include lots of code. Anyway, your review has been helpful, so thank you, and if you have further suggestions for the updated version, please don't hesitate to tell me.